# Alt shortcuts in Java?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio as you use the '`&`' before a letter in the text of a button or etc. for getting a letter underlined shortcut so <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>that letter</kbd> executes the button or etc.

I wanna know how do that in Java. I know it's possible because I have seen underlined letter shortcuts pop up in `JOptionPanes`.

I have tried putting the `&` symbol in `JButton` Text but doesn't work.

Please Help!

Comment: Is step 3 of [this article](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/setting-shortcut-key-and-hotkey-for-menu-item-and-button-in-swing) what you mean?

Comment: Did you search for [hot key java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hot+key+java)

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pragrammatically set this shortcut for each button.
For example:

```
enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
enterButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Shortcut: Alt + Enter
```